# Hacklang — does this type error involving `this` suggest that the underlying object type matters?

Tags: this, subclass, hacklang

I figured the following examples would be typesafe: in all three cases, I am trying to instantiate an `A` that expects `this`, but without much luck:

```php
<?hh // strict
class A {
    public function __construct(?this $next = null) {}
}


// Attempt 1: infer from return type
function foo(): A {
    return new A(foo());
}

// Attempt 2: infer from argument type
function bar(A $A): void {
    new A($A);
}

class B {
    // Attempt 3: infer from property type
    public ?A $A;
    public function baz(): void {
        new A($this->A);
    }
}
```

Because in all cases the typechecker complains that:

> The late-bound type of [the `A` from which the constructor argument originates] needs to be exactly `A`.
>
> Since `A` is not final this might be an instance of a child class.

The only time it doesn't is if an `A` is instantiated within the same scope:

```php
class B {
    public function foo(): void {
        new A(new A());
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that the underlying reason is that the underlying object in all of the failed cases might be a child instance upcast to an `A`? My main confusion is why this renders the instantiation (or, in general, any method call) unsound.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/types/type-system#this):

> `this` can only be used as a *return type* annotation on a *method of a class*. `this` signifies that the method returns an object of the same class on which the method is defined.
>
> The primary purpose of return `this` is to allow chaining of method calls on the instance of the class itself or its subclasses.

In other words, the use of `this` as a type hint is entirely unsupported and may break in future.

As for a general explanation, `this` always means  the **current** instance of a class. It does not mean the current type of class. In a static context this is relaxed a bit to mean the current type, but not all subtypes.

Which brings us to the point, your static code is broken:

1. Attempt 1: foo() is recursively calling itself in an endless loop.
2. Attempt 2: bar() tries to access a member variable called `A` which is not nullable and is also not initialized. (Defined in Attempt 3.) Also, you cannot access a non-static context (`$this`) from a static context.
3. Attempt 3: Again, you are trying to use a not nullable uninitialized member variable named `A`. You can't do that in Hack.

If you want your code to work correctly, you will need to get your OO straightened out.

Comment: Thank you for points 2 and 3. Those were careless errors, and I've modified my example accordingly. However, the `this` type is decently well-developed as a argument type: [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/commit/7e1887c) is indicative. My question still stands: what does the error mean? Clearly not that argument `this` is everywhere illegal.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

The more complete answer is allowing subclasses to inherit a `this`-argumented method is fundamentally flawed. Starting with the basics, function arguments are contravariant, so we can cast them *downward* because the function can accept any subtypes of the type it specifies, but it can't accept supertypes. So, the cast `function(Derived): void` to `function(Base): void` for `Derived <: Base` is invalid. By extension, the following hierarchy is invalid because `Derived <: Base`, but the cast of `Derived` to `Base` casts `foo(...)` in the same way:

```php
<?hh // strict
interface Base {
    public function foo(Base $v): void;
}
interface Derived extends Base {
    <<__Override>>
    public function foo(Derived $v): void;
}
// Derived -> Base means foo(Derived): void -> foo(Base): void
```

Now, note that the `this` type is doing exactly that, even if `Derived` doesn't explicitly override `foo(...)`. In other words, the following is exactly equivalent:

```php
<?hh // strict
interface Base {
    public function foo(this $v): void;
}
interface Derived extends Base {}
```

The simplest violation I can think of:

```php
<?hh
interface Base {
    public function foo(this $v): void;
}
final class Derived implements Base {
    public function bar(): void {}
    public function foo(this $v): void {
        $v->bar(); // trying to call `bar()` on OtherDerived fails miserably!
    }
}
final class OtherDerived implements Base {
    public function foo(this $v): void {}
}
function violate(Base $v, Base $x): void {
    $v->foo($x);
}

bar(new Derived(), new OtherDerived());
```

However, if we can be sure we have a *specific* descendant of `Base`, then we know exactly what its `foo(...)` wants: its own type, and only its own type. We can apply this in general for the overriding shown in the first code block. This isn't very useful in general, but I assume `this` is so nice and concise that it was worth allowing to write the interfaces, then checking every invocation.

---

### Original

Without the error, the following violation would be possible:

```php
<?hh // strict
class A {
    public function act(this $v): void {
        $v->act($this);
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public ?int $b_prop;
    <<__Override>>
    public function act(this $v): void {
        $v->b_prop;
    }
}
function initiate(): void {
    violate(new B());
}
function violate(A $v): void {
    (new A())->act($v);
}
```

I don't know if this is the archetypical violation for this error, but my guess at the rationale:

1. `A::act(this)` is public/protected, so by its existence, there exists at least one method with a `this` argument available to subclasses.
2. The body of `act` can call at least `$v->act` which has a `this` argument.
3. `act` can be called from an `A` context, so the argument `this` is exactly `A`. It follows that `this` in `$v`'s context is *also* cast to `A`.
4. Because `A` is not final, it's possible that `$v` is a proper subtype of `A`.
5. The underlying class of `$v` (in this case, `B`) can override any `this`-argumented methods from `A` under the assumption that `this <: B`. In this case, `$v->b_prop` relies on that assumption.
6. The `A` context thinks it can pass an `A` type (e.g. itself) to the `B` by (3.), but that violates the assumption in (5.)